# Electrical outlet right above bench

Tags: electrical, built-ins

I'm adding a built-in dining nook, something like http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wZ_anvQj-Y4/UIJGonO14dI/AAAAAAAAGsc/70ULoHUcjvw/s640/kitchen_nook.jpg but with cabinets as base.

It covers an electrical outlet on the wall and I'm thinking to move it up a foot, so it sits on the wall higher than the bench. It's relatively an easy relocation, but I'm concerned if there's any hazards as this is a seating area and it will be right behind their back.

I can alternatively move it to the bottom or side, but this has its own complications, and if just moving it up is ok from a safety/regulations concern, I'd rather do that.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: USA   Also found photos of similar benches with outlet in similar position, like http://info.stantonhomes.com/hs-fs/hub/45149/file-1376125727-jpg/images/summerlynkitchenbench.jpg?t=1488568815530

Comment: Your last example is because the bench was an afterthought.  That would not be allowed in a planned design, I can't quote the rule offhand but I'm sure it's in the 90 or 100 section of NEC, i.e. don't put outlets where they'll get abused.

Comment: From which direction does the cable come into the existing box--one side, from below or from above? The reason I ask is you will need enough slack to get the cable into the box at the new location. If the original box was going to be accessible, you could just run new cable to a new box and leave the old one in place. But if it is not accessible you cannot have a splice in the box and put a cover plate over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving it up a foot doesn't violate any codes to my knowledge.  Sure it is in a awkward location but as long as it is grounded correctly and is using a tamper resistant receptacle, there should NOT be any concerns for shock.

As another option, with builtin cabinets the wall outlet requirement is omitted so if possible you could disconnect the circuit from where it is being fed from as long as it does not feed other outlets, or even blank it off with a decorative blank cover.